# use CameraPreview variable in activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I'm trying to use CameraPreview in activity but when I try to use this android studio gets an error. what is my problem?[image]

Comment: What's your error?, please update (edit) post with error description?

Comment: There is no such class in de Android SDK. Are you perhaps referring to [this SDK sample](http://developer.android.com/samples/RuntimePermissions/src/com.example.android.system.runtimepermissions/camera/CameraPreview.html)? If so, and you want to use it, copy the class to your app project first.

Comment: this sample was foe eclips but i wish i could use this in SDK

Comment: i cant understand.whats the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a CameraPreview class in the same folder as your MainActivity.

Here's the code for my preview, you'll have to add some code to your MainActivity as well and maybe edit my code to work with your project.

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

private static final String TAG = CameraPreview.class.getSimpleName();

private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
private Camera mCamera;
private Context mContext;
private List mSupportedPreviewSizes;
private Camera.Size mPreviewSize;

public CameraPreview(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CameraPreview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public void setCameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
    mContext = context;
    mCamera = camera;

    if(mCamera != null) {
        mSupportedPreviewSizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    }

    requestLayout();
    mSurfaceHolder = getHolder();
    mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    mSurfaceHolder.setKeepScreenOn(true);
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("DG_DEBUG", "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int format, int w, int h) {
    if (mSurfaceHolder.getSurface() == null) {
        return;
    }

    try {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
    }

    try {

        Camera.Parameters cameraParameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        List<String> focusModes = cameraParameters.getSupportedFocusModes();

        if (focusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE)) {
            cameraParameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
        }

        List<Camera.Size> previewSizes = cameraParameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
//            List<Camera.Size> pictureSizes = cameraParameters.getSupportedPictureSizes();
        Camera.Size optimalPreviewSize = getOptimalSize(previewSizes, getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels, getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels);
//            Camera.Size optimalPictureSize = getOptimalSize(pictureSizes, getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels, getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels);
        cameraParameters.setPreviewSize(optimalPreviewSize.width, optimalPreviewSize.height);
//            cameraParameters.setPictureSize(optimalPictureSize.width, optimalPictureSize.height);

        mCamera.setParameters(cameraParameters);

        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview" + e.getMessage());
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }
}

private Camera.Size getOptimalSize(List<Camera.Size> sizes, int h, int w) {
    final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.05;
    double targetRatio = (double) w/h;

    if (sizes == null) {
        return null;
    }

    Camera.Size optimalSize = null;

     double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

    int targetHeight = h;

    for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
        double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
        if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE) continue;
        if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
            optimalSize = size;
            minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
        }
    }

    if (optimalSize == null) {
        minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }
    }

    return optimalSize;
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
    if (mCamera != null) {
        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }
    }
}
```

}